# Clickable top menu item in the main menu of Wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, hyperlink

I am trying to make the top menu item clickable when using a custom widget in the menu position.  For some reason I can't figure this out.

[Image http://www.brynhowlett.com/images/yootheme-question.png](http://www.brynhowlett.com/images/yootheme-question.png)

Here is my site: http://www.brynhowlett.com/

Thank you for your time in advance.

Comment: You're going to need to give us your code.  Looking at your site, it's already an `<a>` so just give it an `href=""` and it will link to wherever you want it to go

Comment: What kind of widget are you using? @ntgCleaner That's not how WordPress works unfortunately.

Comment: @ManojKumar What does it matter if wordpress lets you do something or not.  The best thing about wordpress is that you can hack it to do anything you want.  That's the point of it.

Comment: Yes I get what you meant :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways of doing it.

1. Go to `appearance > menus` and create a new menu with all the items in it.

   1.1 Then create sub sections for them items. For example you will create a menu item `Resources` which will have a link to a page maybe called "Resources"

   1.2 Then you can drag and drop items under it for a sub menu.
2. Write the name for the plugin and I shall try my best to help you with that :)

Comment: Hey and thank you for your time, so how those are setup, I am actuating using a Yootheme theme and the menu dropdown are actually custom text widgets in the menu position: ![Image](http://www.brynhowlett.com/images/img-1.png)

Comment: Hey thank you for your time, I am actually using a custom widget placed in the menu position: http://bryntechnologies.com/NEVER-DELETE/img-1.png   -  The Theme creator is Yootheme and I am not actually editing in the menu section under Appearances.  Thanks again for your help.